# Java one line if statement

Tags: java

I am using if condition without braces in java something like

```
if(somecondition)
//Only one line Business logic
```

but some told use braces always even one line statement something like this

```
if(somecondition){
//Only one line Business logic 
}
```

What is the better way according to java sandard?

Comment: depends.. latter is more readable for me

Comment: Its just a good programming practice.

Comment: I know many people that died because they didn't use braces.. So remember to always use braces.

Comment: There are many good answers here already, but this link explains it very well; [braceless-if-considered-harmful](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/)

Comment: `public void foo() {
    if (10/2 == 5) System.out.println("true");
}`

Answer (score 19):

there's no real "standard". i prefer always using braces because if you dont you risk someone adding an innocent looking logging statement turning your code from

```
if(somecondition)
//Only one line Business logic
```

into

```
if(somecondition)
log.debug("condition was true");
//Only one line Business logic
```

and then things stop working :-)

Comment: +1 for example of code breaking. Also, tools like checkstyle usually disallow naked if statements.

Answer (score 16):

That's a matter of taste. I would use braces or else no braces but write all code in one line to improve readability.

Also you might consider using a ternary operator

```
booleanExpression ? value1 : value2
```

Answer (score 8):

In addition to @radai answer, if you are a real evil mind, when you see a if with no braces you can do something that will make you ennemies by adding a semi-colon on the same line of the if but at the 800th column of the line(or something).

like

```
if(condition) /*a loooot of whitespace*/ ;
    //Only one line Business logic that will get executed whatever is the condition
```

This is why i prefer to use braces and recommend people to use them

Comment: I shall ensure this makes it into production later today

Comment: :) you evil mastermind !

Comment: This is why I show whitespace in my IDE.

Answer (score 5):

No naked if statements.  You're just asking for trouble.  Always use { }

Answer (score 2):

it is better to use braces when checking for errors or updating the code.

imagine.

```
if(answer.equals("add"))
    addedValue += Scanner.readInt();
```

but you have a new requirement to add only the absolute value, so you change to.

```
if(answer.equals("add2))
    valueToBeAdded = Scanner.readInt();
    if(valueToBeAdded < 0) valueToBeAdded = - valueToBeAdded;
    addedValue += valueToBeAdded;
```

this is not a really correct algorithm, is just an example of what can happens.

Answer (score 1):

Using if statement with braces is better way to java standard, because it increase the readability and reduce unwanted error.

Answer (score 1):

The two statements have exactly the same effect but I have suffered so often from the lack of braces that I also always comment that there should be braces even around 1 line statements. This makes the code easier to maintain and can save a lot of headache. My experience shows that one line if statements often turn into multi-line statements on later iterations so what you save by not writing two `{` the first time, you will give later on.

Answer (score 0):

According to java standard braces are better because if they are not there compiler has to work around more and also would be performance issue.

Comment: Performance issue? You mean the extra time taken for compiling?

Comment: yes as compiler has to consider only for one line among the statement if there were no braces